# Map two columns to auto-populate data in Excel

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet which contains definitions for codes and I want it to auto-populate whenever I type the code. For example:

```
Column A  Column B
--------  ------------
ANI       Ancient
BCP       Black Copper
BP        Black Pearl
```

The above table is a reference table. There are multiple values from column A in column D. So I want to convert those codes to values corresponding to column B.

Comment: And just where is it supposed to get the list of words for column B along with their corresponding 'typed words' from column A?

Comment: That list with column A,B is already with me. I have to create a new list from this.

Comment: What are you doing this for? Could you have columns that you use, but are hidden for other people, for example? Otherwise, you would need to do it with a macro.

Comment: I have a large sheet with all code words and I have to convert them to their definitions according to the above table.

Comment: That didn't answer the hidden column question. If you can do that, I'd go with Grade 'Eh' Bacon's answer below.

Comment: Because I am working in google spreadsheets.

Comment: @pnuts since it's related to excel too as per me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean just put a value in column E, next to column D, that pulls the full name from column B when column D matches column A? That would simply look like this, in cell E2 and dragged down:

```
=vlookup(D2,A:B,2)
```

Comment: The table with code is like reference table and column D will have multiple values from column A which I want to convert to corresponding values from B

Comment: If you want to type one thing in a cell and have it turn into another thing in the same cell, you will need to use a macro. If you are okay typing it in column D but appearing in column E, you can do what Ive shown here.

Comment: I tried this formula but it works till A,B range equals to D and after that it doesn't.

Comment: Make sure your matches are all spelled exactly the same. Should work as far down as you need.

Comment: thanks for pointing in right direction, I was able to solve it.